In Spark 3.5.0+, performance differences between Python UDTF vs Custom Python Data Source?
Spark 3.5.0 (well, actually Databricks 15.4)
Let's say I need to implement a custom batch data source reader from (somewhere), it will be reading medium-sized data (up to 100m rows).
One way to approaching this is via Python UDTF
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/sql/python_udtf.html
Another way a recently introduced Custom Python (PySpark) Data Source.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/4.0.0-preview1/api/python/user_guide/sql/python_data_source.html
Both are somewhat similar logically and from the coding perspective (how the class is defined).
Is there a reason to expect a performance difference between both approaches, or are they actually share a similar back-end implementation (UDTF) and custom data source is more of a syntactic wrapper over UDTFs?
